# Change text of delete button on UItable cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

I want to change the text of the delete button in red that comes up when we swipe on a table cell. Is that possible?? if possible can you please tell how to do that.

Thank you :) \m/ \m/

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can try like this,

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return @"Name";
}
```